# What directory do I need to copy resource files to for dashboards?

Tags: apache-superset

I installed superset in docker. While creating a dashboard, I needed to specify an image:

`<img src="/location/logo.jpg">`

But superset is not recognizing the location. Can someone tell me which location I need to copy logo.jpg so that superset can recognize image from the path specified in the `<img>` tag? Which location in superset installation I need to  use as image resource to specify in src attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `/superset/static/assets` directory is what you're looking for. The url would look like `/static/assets/logo.jpg`.